# Трансляция видео с IP камер

Tags: веб-программирование, centos

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Имеется вот такая задачка:
Дано K IP камер и P пользователей. Пользователям необходимо транслировать видео в реальном времени. Пользователи находятся в разных городах России. Схема трансляции гибкая. Т.е. пользователю P1 транслируется видео с камер K1, K5, K6 (к примеру). Пользователю P2 транслируются потоки K1, K6, K8.

Предполагаю использовать следующую архитектуру:
1. Один центральный сервер с CentOS, на который будут поступать видео со всех K камер.
2. На этом же сервере (смотрите пункт 1) крутится сайт.
3. Пользователь авторизуется на сайте и ему на одной страничке транслируется видео с разных камер.

Максимальное количество камер на ближайшее время - около 100.
Максимальное количество пользователей на ближайшее время - около 1000.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ответы на следующие вопросы:
1. Какие протоколы передачи видео лучше использовать? Видео необходимо передавать в реальном времени, задержка довольно критична, пользователи в разных городах России. Качество видео - пока не очень критично.
2. Каковы минимальные требования к железу сервера?
3. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, бюджетные варианты IP камер для данной задачи.
4. Если есть более продуктивная архитектура, буду рад выслушать.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблемы с работоспособностью сервера или атака на сайт и вы получаете звонки от 1000 рассерженных пользователей и невозможность вести запись со всех 100 камер. ИМХО лучше делать распределенную систему с отдельными серверами по районам. И один центральный сервер под сайт. Так вы сможете ограничить ваши потери от возможных неполадок. На вопросы ответа дать не смогу, т.к. не занимаюсь видеонаблюдением.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону Beward, Axis, Microdigital или Samsung камеры, про качество остальных (качество камер, а не видеопотока) ничего сказать не могу, камеры этих производителей мы ставим клиентам, они ими довольны. Самый бюджетный вариант: D-Link (не советую) или камеры на базе Raspbery Pi. Самый распространенный протокол - rtsp. На монитор не имеет смысла выводить более 16 камер, лучше ограничивать 8ю.

Вам придется транслировать все потоки от камер пользователям, сомневаюсь, что мощности 1го сервера вам хватит при условии 100 камер. Если вы еще собираетесь конвертировать поток в другой формат, то можете смело закладывать 10 серверов.

Все вышеизложенное написано на вскидку, более точную информацию необходимо детально рассчитывать.

Comment: Спасибо. Предположим, будет выделено N серверов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью чего можно балансировать нагрузку между серверами, а также в случае отказа одного сервера, распределять потоки на действующие?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно для трансляции вам подойдёт выбор протокола WebRTC, он уже реализован в большинстве браузеров. Сервер можно использовать только для авторизации и перенаправления пользователей на нужную/доступную камеру. 
Потоки видео/аудио будут идти напрямую, а не через сервер.
Пару ссылок для почитать:
- [раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/324294/)
- [два](https://habrahabr.ru/post/229243/)